# Drupal webform submission creating new table

Tags: drupal-7, phpmyadmin, acquia

I have created a webform. However I want that whenever I create a new webform and if I input some data and submit it, It must create new table in phpmyadmin for every new form that I create.
By default every submitted data goes to "webform_submitted_data" table. I want every webform that I create must have separate table.
Please give me steps on how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the webform module as is, it will use its own database table structure exactly as you describe.

If you have *particular requirements on how the data of your webforms is stored in the backend*, you'll have to create your own custom module that either builds its own forms and does the data storing itself or that hooks into the existing webform functionality and changes just the storing and retrieving part of it.

In either case, it'll be a bit of work on your part to build that custom module.

How the data is stored isn't something you can just **configure** for the webform module...  :-)

However, I'm not sure why you want to change the way the data is stored, but you're aware that you can export the submissions data as csv and other file formats to manipulate later, right?

Comment: Thanks Boriana. It is the requirement for the project that for each created webform a separate database table must be created at the back end.Any pointers to create that kind of module will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The [webforms mysql view](https://drupal.org/project/webform_mysql_views) module will give you a pseudo-table for each webform,  allowing read access to the data.